# Task Scheduler registration deleted at startup trigger (event 141)

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, gpo

I have created a task scheduler to run a simple copy cmd script that need elevation privilege to run. I have tried using GPO (Computer Configuration) copy files or GPO startup script but It can't do the copy since the files are inside System32. So the only way is to use `Task Scheduler` (Run with highest privileges).

I did all the configuration via GPO to propagate the task scheduler and all go well besides the part that after the task is triggered the task get automatic delete and the action isn't running.

If I click `Run` manually as seen below all go ok without any promt or other error. So my question is why task scheduler doesn't take action when it is called by `Computer startup` ?

Why the `Action Started` start only after I manually press `Run` and `Task triggered by user`

[image]

[image]

the red line is before and after i press the `Run` button

[image]

Comment: did you check the *run whether user is logged on or not* parameter of this task ?

Comment: yes, in fact i copied a running scheduler task that I have created 1 year ago (added now General screen)

Answer (score 0):

I went with `Triggers` : `At task creation/modfication` and adding a 30 min delay for not slowing the startup and user login proccess and all went well as seen below. I don't know what the problem with windows but the `At Startup` doesn't work. (I hope this help others that want to execute and CMD with elevated privileges on domain PC-s as one-time command)

[image]